# Android Button Click Crashes App

Tags: java, android

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Line.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

My cellphone alert "Sorry,The program has stopped working".

Why?

This is the error. http://www.mgiga.com.tw:8080/mo/01.jsp

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)?

Comment: Use the `edit` button at the bottom of your post.

Comment: This is the error. http://www.mgiga.com.tw:8080/mo/01.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Line` is an [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you haven't declare it inside [`manifest`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). Thats why you get [ActivityNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html).

**Edit :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sample.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dragimagedemo.Line" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: add another `Activity` named `Line` post manifest file I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Here you are.On the top.

Comment: com.example.dragimagedemo.Line = com.sample.activity.Line

Comment: your `Line` activity is inside `com.example.dragimagedemo` package that why from your error screenshot.

Comment: what truth u r talking about ?

Comment: The package is com.sample.activity.Line

Comment: it is not same there are 2 different packages in ur project

Answer (score 4):

Best if you could share the error you get in your logcat

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Line.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Because your program can crash because of a lot of reasons.

Comment: The cellphone still alert "Sorry,The program has stopped working".

Comment: When you run/push your app to your phone, look at the bottom of your IDE (Android Studio / Eclipse) and see the error.

Comment: Good as you can see it says on the second red line "unable to find explicit activity class". This means your class is not defined in your android manifest file, probably you copy pasted the code from somewhere... to quick and easy fix this delete the MainActivity class then using the IDE select > file > new Activity (Do this for both MainActivity class and Line class, this way it will generate the code required in the manifest file)... then just paste the code above.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is some problem in your second activity("Line.class") not in button click. Make another demo activity with "hello world" & check that still your app crashes or not. Example: if your demo activity named "`DemoActivity`" Then write code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you give Logcat error then it is better understandable for us.

Edited: add activity in your manifest.xml

```
<activity
android:name="YourPackageName.Line"
android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Activity needs to add in manifest file. IDE automatic adds it if we use IDE. other wise we need to add it manually. See my edited answer.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.sample.activity.Line"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, "YourPackageName.Line");
startActivity(intent);

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Line"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Dear error is already told you have not declare Line Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: How can I fix this problem?I had added the activity.